# How can I get percentage in LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq

My question is: how can I get this translated to LINQ?

```
select Reasons.Description, count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over() AS Porcentage
from Rejected
iNNER JOIN Reasons
ON Rejected.Reason = Reasons.ReasonID
group by Reasons.Description
```

Or how can I fill a Ilist with this result, in case I want to use stored procedure.

What I'm trying to do it's just get the percentage of each 'Description type' in numeric so I can later on fill a donut-chart.

Thanks

Comment: are you using entity framework?

Comment: Instead of making this a CTE I would use a nested query to get the grouped counts and the outer query to translate that into a percentage. That would be easier to translate into Linq to Entities, I am not even sure it is possible to translate a CTE.

Comment: Yes using entity framework

Comment: @Igor that make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend getting the raw counts from your data store and then figure the percentages either in the app tier or allow your chart component to determine the percentages based on that raw value. Something like this should work:

```cs
var query = (from reason in dc.Reasons
            join reject in dc.Rejections on reason.ReasonID equals reject.Reason
            group reason by reason.Description into grouped
            select new { Reason = grouped.Key, ItemCount = grouped.Count() })
            .ToList(); 

// If you really need to generate the averages and not let your charting component figure the percentages out for you:
var totalItems = query.Sum(q => q.ItemCount);
var averages = query.Select(q => new { q.Reason, Average = q.ItemCount / totalItems * 100});
```

If you prefer lambdas over query syntax, look into GroupJoin.